# Do I break even in a fair game?

Tags: probability, soft-question, intuition, expected-value, standard-deviation

Thanks for reading. The following screenshot I took from the book *"The Art of Probability"* by Richard Hamming.

[image]

I'm really confused.

How is it that the probability of heads is $\frac{1}{2}$, meaning that we expect to get heads around half the time after a large number of tosses, yet the author of this book is telling us that we should expect the score to deviate by $\sqrt{n}$ after a large number of tosses?!

I always thought that if I played a fair game, the more times I played that game the more I would expect to "break-even"! But according to this guy, I don't!

---

**Update:**

In general, I'm a little confused as to how to interpret the expected value of $X$ vs the standard deviation of $Y$. In my comments *(both below and to the top answer thus far)* I think I make my confusion pretty clear!

Additionally, let's say I let a new random variable $Z$ correspond to the sum of a bunch of $Y_s$, say $m$ of them. How would I interpret $Z$s expected value and standard deviation?!?!?!

Thank you!

Comment: His explanation is pretty confusing, but think of it like this: if you toss a fair coin $2n$ times, how likely are you to see exactly $n$ heads? Intuitively, as an $n$ gets large, we are more likely to see more variance in the number of heads, even if the proportion of heads narrows around 1/2. For example, in 1000 tosses seeing  510 heads sounds reasonable even though we saw 10 more heads than we'd expect. This is the same idea as the passage. The game is fair, so the proportion of games Player 1 wins concentrates near 1/2, but the total number of games they win will likely vary more.

Comment: "Expected value" is one of the worst-named terms in all of math.

Comment: You break even in percentage terms: that is your earnings per game converges to zero. Your total earnings, on the other hand, will exceed $\sqrt{n}$ and go below $-\sqrt n$ infinitely often. This means your earnings per game goes outside $\pm 1/\sqrt{n}$ infinitely often, which is consistent with it going to zero.

Comment: And that's assuming the bet size stays fixed. (And also more importantly that you have infinite wealth to take swings of all sizes.) If instead you always bet a certain fraction of your wealth, then your wealth will always converge to zero, even as your "expected" wealth is exactly whatever you start out with.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you for those comments (they should really be answers tbh)! Look at my comment on the answer below - I'm still confused!

Comment: @EdgarJaramilloRodriguez so..,wait a sec, I think I finally understand! Pretty much a standard deviation in $Y$ of $\sqrt{n}$ doesn't disagree with the fact that the expected value of $X$ is $0$, because $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$ still goes to $0$ as $n$ gets large! That is, expecting $\sqrt{n}$ away from $0$ and expecting around $0$ gain isn't contradicting each other, since $\sqrt{n}$ is small relative to $n$?! Also, look at my comment on the answer below, and thanks!!!

Comment: @EdgarJaramilloRodriguez let's say I let a new random variable $Z$ correspond to the sum of a bunch of $Y_s$, say $m$ of them. How would I interpret $Z$s expected value and standard deviation?!?!?!

Comment: @JoshuaRonis Yes, that’s right. Your average earning (i.e. your earning per game) stays approximately within $\pm 1/\sqrt{n}$ of zero, which gets tighter and tighter as time goes on. This is the convergence the law of large numbers is referring to, and it is consistent with the fluctuations in **total** earnings getting larger as $\sqrt n$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks so much!  I'm re-reading your comments, and it all makes sense now. I'm just leaving this final comment for myself to look back at. In my question, my original confusion was captured in *"I always thought that if I played a fair game.....to this guy, I don't!"* However, the reality is that I DO break even! If you think about it, it's **proportionally** more "even" to lose 6000 times in 10,000 games than it is to lose 2 times in 3 games. In the second, I lost 2/3 the times! The fact that I lost a lot more money playing more doesn't contradict that this is a fair game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you start with $\$1000$ and play $100$ games where you bet $\$1$ on each win. That's a fair game, so the expected value you end up with is $\$1000$.

However, that doesn't mean you'll always end up with exactly $\$1000$. What if you lose all $100$ games? It's unlikely, but still possible, and you'd end up with $\$900$. With the same low probability you could win all $100$ games and end up with $\$1100$. In fact, it's rather unlikely that you end up with *exactly* $\$1000$, the chance for that is only about $8\%$.

Of course you'll still end up close to $\$1000$. But how close? One mathematical way to quantify that is the *variance* of a distribution. Suppose your *score* at the end of the game is the square of the difference between your actual balance and the expected balance. Then the variance is simply the expected value of your score. In this case, the variance is exactly $\$^2 100$.

The *standard deviation* is the square root of the variance, so in this case $\$10$. It's a good approximation (up to a constant factor) of the *average absolute deviation* of this game, which would be the average absolute number of dollars your balance changes by and is probably what interests you here.

Now the nice thing about variances is that variances of sums of independent variables add up! The variance of a single game is $\$^21$, and all games are independent, so the variance of $n$ games is $\$^2n$. So the standard deviation after $n$ games is $\$\sqrt n$, so the average absolute deviation is about $\$c \sqrt n$ for some constant $c = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \approx 0.7979$.

Now let's look at what happened in the end. One player won, and one player lost. The money the winner has is on average exactly $\$1000$ plus the average absolute deviation, since that's the definition of the average absolute deviation. Of course the loser has on average exactly $\$1000$ *minus* the average absolute deviation.

Note that the winner depends on the outcome of the game, so you can't just go ahead and say "I expect to end up with on average about $\$8$ less money." No, what you can say is that "I expect to end up with on average about $\$8$ less money *in case I lose*", and you can also say that "I expect to end up with on average about $\$8$ *more* money in case I win."

To finally answer your question: Most of the time you won't break even, either gaining or losing a few dollars. But *on average* that gain or loss balances out, so the *expected* amount of money you gain is zero. Remember that "expected" is a technical term that doesn't quite match up with the regular English word, so for example even though the *expected* number of heads in a coin flip is $\frac 12$, you shouldn't end up *expecting* to see half a head.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1! But, I'm still confused. The standard deviation of $X$ is around what I expect the scores to deviate by from the expected value after one toss. That's +1, which makes perfect sense. The standard deviation of $Y$ is by how much I should expect the scores to deviate by from the expected value after $n$ tosses. That's $\sqrt{n}$. All good...but here's the thing. The expected value of $X$ told me that after a large number of tosses, say $n$ tosses, I should expect the score to be around $0$...so doesn't that contradict the standard deviation of $Y$? Thanks again!

Comment: It should be around $0$, but the scale of variation is the standard deviation.  You should be in the range $-Y$ to $+Y$ about $68.3\%$ of the time and within $-2Y$ to $+2Y$ about $95\%$ of the time.  Note that $Y$ grows with the square root of the number of tosses, so you expect to be fractionally closer as the number of tosses increases, even to you may be further away in absolute number.

Comment: @RossMillikan got you! A standard deviation of $\sqrt{n}$ **is** in the range of around $0$ relative to $n$, if we consider the fact that we're playing an **infinite** number of games *$n$ is tending to infinity*!!!